# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - nginx configuration for python (3.7 on AL2) flask app

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to get a simple flask (python) app running on elastic beanstalk with an nginx server.

The python app appears to start up ok with the following config in my .ebextensions application.config:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: application:application
```

gunicorn appears to bind itself ok to the app - see:

```
Nov 30 07:40:00 ip-172-31-19-88 web: [2021-11-30 07:40:00 +0000] [32041] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Nov 30 07:40:00 ip-172-31-19-88 web: [2021-11-30 07:40:00 +0000] [32041] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (32041)
Nov 30 07:40:00 ip-172-31-19-88 web: [2021-11-30 07:40:00 +0000] [32041] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
Nov 30 07:40:00 ip-172-31-19-88 web: [2021-11-30 07:40:00 +0000] [32098] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32098
```

When I visit the web url, the browser just hangs for a long time (minutes) and eventually times out with "took too long to respond".

I believe it has something to do with the NGINX config not proxy'ing the requests correctly - so I've tried adding the following to .ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf

```
server {
      location / {
          proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8000;
          proxy_http_version  1.1;
          proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }
}
```

but that doesn't appear to do anything.

Any ideas on what the issue could be? I'm not sure its NGINX but it does appear to be at that layer where the issue is occuring... the web server doesn't appear to know what to do with my web request.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf` is **incorrect path**. On AL2, nginx [should be customized](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) using `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` or `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` if you are overwriting entire nginx.conf.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin.  I moved the file to .platform/nginx/conf.d/myconf.conf and redeployed but the issue didnt change. Still taking ages and then eventually timing out.

Comment: @JohnChristian Your change may require rewriting entire nginx.conf. In that cause you have to provide full `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that in order to get a hello world flask app up and running that I'd need to supply an entire config? doesnt make sense. I might as well use EC2 in that case.

Comment: @JohnChristian Normally it works out of the box. I don't know what you are doing with the flask app. You haven't provided any details about your setup. You can make a new question for that.